# Visual Studio 2010 SDL_Event errors

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, sdl

I'm trying to create an SDL game with Visual Studio 2010, but I'm getting a lot of compile errors when I try to build the project. I followed [this tutorial](http://lazyfoo.net/SDL_tutorials/lesson01/windows/msvsnet2010e/index.php) to set up Visual Studio, and I'm following [this tutorial for SDL](http://www.sdltutorials.com/sdl-tutorial-basics?CommentsPage=0#Comments). The two portions of code that are giving me these errors is my CApp_OnEvent and CApp files.

CApp_OnEvent:

```
#include "CApp.h"

void CApp::OnEvent(SDL_EVENT* Event) {
}
```

CApp:

```
#include "CApp.h"

CApp::CApp() {
Running = true;
}

int CApp::OnExecute() {
if(OnInit() == false) {
    return -1;
}

SDL_EVENT Event;

while(Running) {
    while(SDL_PollEvent(&Event)) {
        OnEvent(&Event);
    }

    OnLoop();
    OnRender();
}

OnCleanup();

return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
CApp theApp;

return theApp.OnExecute();
}
```

Here's the output of Visual Studio when I try to build it:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: SDL Game, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>Build started 11/24/2011 10:58:45 AM.
1>InitializeBuildStatus:
1>  Touching "Debug\SDL Game.unsuccessfulbuild".
1>ClCompile:
1>  CApp_OnRender.cpp
1>c:\users\nathan\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\sdl game\sdl game\capp.h(18): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'SDL_EVENT'
1>  CApp_OnLoop.cpp
1>c:\users\nathan\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\sdl game\sdl game\capp.h(18): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'SDL_EVENT'
1>  CApp_OnInit.cpp
1>c:\users\nathan\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\sdl game\sdl game\capp.h(18): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'SDL_EVENT'
1>  CApp_OnEvent.cpp
1>c:\users\nathan\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\sdl game\sdl game\capp.h(18): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'SDL_EVENT'
1>c:\users\nathan\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\sdl game\sdl game\capp_onevent.cpp(3): error C2065: 'SDL_EVENT' : undeclared identifier
1>c:\users\nathan\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\sdl game\sdl game\capp_onevent.cpp(3): error C2065: 'Event' : undeclared identifier
1>c:\users\nathan\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\sdl game\sdl game\capp_onevent.cpp(3): error C2448: 'CApp::OnEvent' : function-style initializer appears to be a function definition
1>  CApp_OnCleanup.cpp
1>c:\users\nathan\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\sdl game\sdl game\capp.h(18): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'SDL_EVENT'
1>  CApp.cpp
1>c:\users\nathan\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\sdl game\sdl game\capp.h(18): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'SDL_EVENT'
1>c:\users\nathan\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\sdl game\sdl game\capp.cpp(12): error C2065: 'SDL_EVENT' : undeclared identifier
1>c:\users\nathan\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\sdl game\sdl game\capp.cpp(12): error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'Event'
1>c:\users\nathan\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\sdl game\sdl game\capp.cpp(12): error C2065: 'Event' : undeclared identifier
1>c:\users\nathan\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\sdl game\sdl game\capp.cpp(15): error C2065: 'Event' : undeclared identifier
1>c:\users\nathan\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\sdl game\sdl game\capp.cpp(15): error C3861: 'SDL_PollEvent': identifier not found
1>c:\users\nathan\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\sdl game\sdl game\capp.cpp(16): error C2065: 'Event' : undeclared identifier
1>  Generating Code...
1>
1>Build FAILED.
1>
1>Time Elapsed 00:00:00.24
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

You can view the rest of my project code by going here:
http://www.mediafire.com/download.php?5524qr1zodracc5

Any ideas on why I'm getting these errors? Thanks!

Comment: Can you open SDL.h in you project? May be you forgot to add additional include directories in the project properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I've answered my own question again. I needed to be using SDL_Event, not SDL_EVENT.

*hangs head in shame for such a stupid mistake*